# Trivial question about Boole's inequality

Tags: probability

I have a fairly easy question, I probably miss something trivial but that's why we are here.

So, from Kolmogorovs axioms we can deduce that, for arbitrary events $A$ and $B$ we have that
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).
$$
On the other hand Boole's inequality states that for arbitrary events $A$ and $B$ we have
$$
P(A\cup B)\le P(A)+P(B)
$$
since $P(E)\ge 0$ for any events $E$, I see these two contradict. Am I missing some assumptions?

Comment: From first, you can write $P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)\geq P(A\cup B)$ since $P(A\cap B)\geq 0$. There is no contradition.

Comment: Substitute the rhs of the equation for the lhs of the inequality.

Comment: $P(E) \geq 0$, then $-P(E) \leq 0$. On the right hand side, we are therefore adding the *negative* quantity $P(A \cap B)$. That makes Boole's inequality a correct inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem here? $$P(A\cap B) \geq 0 \Rightarrow -P(A\cap B) \leq 0$$

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) \leq P(A) + P(B).$$